# How gwt events work on low level

Tags: gwt

I want to learn how gwt handles browser events and wraps them with its own events in a way that doesn't cause memory leaks. I mean sinkevents and stuff around it. Can anybody give me a link to an article or forum post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/dom_events_memory_leaks_and_you

Comment: I've seen this article. I need more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/DomEventsAndMemoryLeaks and http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/UnderstandingMemoryLeaks